# find all file modify after specific date (Centos)

Tags: unix, centos6

i'm search some command in unix to find all file modify after a specific date:

if i use this command i recive i get this error :

```
 ls -lt $(find .) | grep '16 feb' | grep -o './[^\N]*'

-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

and if i use this command i recive all file sorted by date.

```
 find /folder -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r 

2016-04-05 14:50:53.1730441170 /folder/a.txt 
2016-04-05 14:46:56.3400447050 /folder/b.txt 
2016-04-05 12:50:27.3930543890 /folder/c.txt 
2016-04-05 12:49:47.0190544440 /folder/d.txt 
2016-04-05 12:23:19.7660566060 /folder/e.txt
```

there is some to do something like the second code with a specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your second command and include `grep` at the end.

`find /folder -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' |grep <date to find>`

Comment: in this mode i find only on a specific date i need to find AFTER that date

Comment: If you know how many days back you need to go, you can use := `find /folder -type f -mtime -7 -print` , will give you files modified in last 7 days. You can adjust `mtime` value to suit your needs.